# Increase element width with jqLite

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

In my angularjs directive I want to increase DIV width if vertical scroll bar is visible. I did the following with jQuery:

```
var gridBody = gridElem.children().eq(1);
var scrollBarWidth = gridBody[0].offsetWidth - gridBody[0].clientWidth;
var lastCol = angular.element(gridElem[0].querySelector('.grid-header-last-cell'));
lastCol.width(lastCol.width() + scrollBarWidth);
```

It seems to work (not sure about cross browser issues). Notice that width() method is jQuery method but jqLite. How can I achieve the same result with jqLite only?

Comment: There is nothing wrong to use jQuery in directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```
lastCol.css('width', '+=' + scrollBarWidth);
```

Comment: Your answer tripped the low quality filter and showed up in the review queue. Can you add some detail to your answer? Documentation, explanation, etc...